# proof verification on $ f_{n}$ uniformly continuity

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Let $f_{n}:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$f_{n}=\begin{cases}
nx & \text{ if } 0\leq x\leq \frac{1}{n}\\ 
 1& \text{ if } \frac{1}{n}<x\leq 1
\end{cases}$

is $f_{n}\xrightarrow[]{uni}f$?

my solution:

for $x=0 ,f_{n}=0$

for $0<x\leq 1$ it exist a $n_{0}$ such that $\frac{1}{n_{0}}<x $ so $x>\frac{1}{n}$ for every $n \geq n_{0} $
$\Rightarrow f_{n}\rightarrow f(x)=1$

now i will check if it goes uniformly to $1$

$\left | f_{n}-1 \right |\geq nx-1$ for every $n\epsilon \mathbb{N},x\epsilon X$

$\left \| f_{n}-1\right \|>nx-2$ let $n\rightarrow +\infty $

$\left \| f_{n}-1\right \|\rightarrow +\infty $

I am not sure about the inequalities, is this ok? Can someone formally prove it?

Comment: Please use $\in$ (with the command \in) for inclusion symbol and not epsilon. This looks horrible. Also, please write $f_n(x)$ consistently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is actually a bounded sequence. Indeed, $0 \leq f_n(x) \leq 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in [0,1]$. So your conclusion that $\|f_n-1\| \to \infty$ is incorrect.

The easiest way to see that $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ does not converge uniformly is that the limit function $f$ is discontinuous (note that the $f_n$ are continuous). But the uniform limit of a sequence of continuous functions has to be continuous. Hence the convergence can't be uniform.

Answer (score 1):

One has
\begin{equation}
(f_{2n} - f_{n})\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right) =  1-\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}\quad \Longrightarrow
\quad \|f_{2n}-f_{n}\|_{\infty}\ge \frac{1}{2}\end{equation}
Hence the convergence cannot be uniform.

Comment: it was so easy it just never cross my mind ..as allways , any way thanks for the answer